# Change BackColor of a DataGridViewRow

Tags: c#, winforms

I know this question have been up a lot. I've probably checked them all, but no one is working for me. I have two examples which I mark as my favorites and think SHOULD work, but it doesn't.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gridResults.Rows)
   row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000");
```

and

```
for (int row = 0; row < gridResults.RowCount; row++ )
    gridResults.Rows[row].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

For some reason, these doesn't work. And I've tried multiple others suggested from stackoverflow users (and the intertube outside that!) - but it simply doesn't work.

This makes me wonder if I got some property or similiar in my application that inactivates the ability to change row backcolor. I know it sounds strange, but anyone recognize this problem?

Comment: Did you try this `gridResults.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;`? I guess you do this when you don't have the rows. is it?

Comment: no, its a good guess though :) Its just red of random reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears, this code above only works when putting it in onLoad, mine was in the constructor.. Which was a big fault itself :P

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can handle two events that can handle the background color of the cell if meet some condition, are the following events :

- [RowCellStyle](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowCellStyletopic)
- [CustomDrawCell](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomDrawCelltopic)

The **CustomDrawCell** event is raised before a data cell is painted. The cell that is going to be painted is identified by the [RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs](https://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseRowCellCustomDrawEventArgs_RowHandletopic.aspx).RowHandle and [RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs.Column](https://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseRowCellCustomDrawEventArgs_Columntopic.aspx) parameters.

See the following example :

```
private void advBandedGridView1_CustomDrawCell(object sender, RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e) 
{
   GridView currentView = sender as GridView;
   if(e.RowHandle == currentView.FocusedRowHandle) return;
   Rectangle r = e.Bounds;

   if(e.Column.FieldName == "UnitsInStock") 
   {
      bool check = (bool)currentView.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, 
      currentView.Columns["Discontinued"]);

      if(check) 
      {
        //Change the text to display
        //The e.Handled parameter is false
        //So the cell will be painted using the default appearance settings
        e.DisplayText = "Discontinued";                    
       }
       else 
       {
        // If the cell value is greater then 50 the paint color is LightGreen, 
        // otherwise LightSkyBlue 
        Brush ellipseBrush = Brushes.LightSkyBlue;

        if (Convert.ToInt16(e.CellValue) > 50) ellipseBrush = Brushes.LightGreen;

        //Draw an ellipse within the cell
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(ellipseBrush, r);
        r.Width -= 12;

        //Draw the cell value
        e.Appearance.DrawString(e.Cache, e.DisplayText, r);

        //Set e.Handled to true to prevent default painting
        e.Handled = true;
       }
   }
}
```

The **RowCellStyle** event is raised for individual cells before they need to be repainted. The referenced cell can be identified using the event's [CustomRowCellEventArgs.RowHandle](https://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseCustomRowCellEventArgs_RowHandletopic.aspx) and [CustomRowCellEventArgs.Column](https://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseCustomRowCellEventArgs_Columntopic.aspx) parameters. 
To customize the cell's appearance settings, use the [RowCellStyleEventArgs.Appearance](https://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridRowCellStyleEventArgs_Appearancetopic.aspx) property.

See the following example :

```
private void gridView1_RowCellStyle(object sender, RowCellStyleEventArgs e) 
{
    if(e.RowHandle != gridView1.FocusedRowHandle && ((e.RowHandle % 2 == 0 && e.Column.VisibleIndex % 2 == 1) || (e.Column.VisibleIndex % 2 == 0 && e.RowHandle % 2 == 1)))    
      e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.NavajoWhite;
 }
```

I hope this help you.